# Moving custom field from magnolia 5 to magnolia 6

Tags: java, magnolia

I'm trying to move my custom field from magnolia 5 to magnolia 6. I'm using

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
       <artifactId>magnolia-ui-framework-compatibility</artifactId>
       <version>6.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>info.magnolia.pages</groupId>
     <artifactId>magnolia-pages-app-compatibility</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

So as result, my custom field does work on my custom app, which I have, but it doesn't on pages app.

This is what I see in the dialog:
[image]

And this is the log:

```
2021-05-27 18:20:35,692 ERROR inition.migration.FallbackFieldDefinitionConverter: No converter for old class com.example.uimodule.field.definition.MyCustomFieldDefinition. Falling back to class info.magnolia.ui.field.StaticFieldViewDefinition.
```

My Definition class extends ConfiguredFieldDefinition from magnolia-ui-framework-compatibility module.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving from 5.7.x to 6.2.x, and you've got custom fields, it's not always a simple matter.  There's some background and examples [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bCjcVHAzf3AvpWOjKoL8t2DhuZapTzyU32KG_G4nbIE/edit?usp=sharing).